# Combining 2 temp tables to aggregate into a single table

Tags: stored-procedures, aggregate

I'm working on a SP that takes a lot of data, separates it into two temp tables and unions those two together.  It works, but right now it's giving me a different line for each of temp tables, but I need it to grab it into one line.

```
USE CallDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LDS_ALL_CALLS_120s_PLUS]
AS
BEGIN
end end 



--Pulls all unique calls from CallDB into temp table #tmpTotCalls

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTotCalls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpTotCalls

SELECT DISTINCT [user],count(*) as [TotCall]
  into #tmpTotCalls
  FROM CallDB
  WHERE status <> 'ALTNUM' --and length_in_sec >= '120'
  GROUP by [user]

--Pulls all unique calls OVER 120 seconds from 
CallDB into temp table #tmp120s

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp120s') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp120s

SELECT DISTINCT [user], count(*) as [120calls]
  into #tmp120s
  FROM CallDB
  WHERE status <> 'ALTNUM' and length_in_sec >= '120'
  GROUP by [user]

delete CallDB.[dbo].[120s_calls]
insert into CallDB.[dbo].[120s_calls]

Select [user], TotCall, '0' as [120calls] from #tmpTotCalls 

UNION ALL

select [USER], '0' as [Totcall], [120calls] from #tmp120s

Order by [user]

DROP TABLE #tmp120s
DROP TABLE #tmpTotCalls

select * from CallDB.[dbo].[120s_calls]

END
```

What I get, as a solution is:

```
User | totCalls | 120Calls
fernandezv | 0 | 23
fernandezv | 2147 | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you need a `JOIN` instead of a `UNION`:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(T1.[user],T2.[user]) [user],
        ISNULL(T1.TotCall,0) TotCall,
        ISNULL(T2.[120Calls],0) [120Calls]
FROM #tmpTotCalls T1
FULL JOIN #tmp120s T2
      ON T1.[user] = T2.[user]
;
```

Comment: I'll accept when I can, this worked, thank you so much!